# Using docker the way Openshift does?

Tags: docker, heroku, kubernetes, openshift, dokku

I read this [How does docker compare to openshift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840342/how-does-docker-compare-to-openshift)

But I have a question : 
This is an extremely simplified description of what usually devs do with Openshift :

1. Select a "pod" (let's say a JBoss/Wildfly container)
2. From within Openshift you point to your github repo
3. Openshift would clone the repo, build it and deploy it
4. Openshift present you with a web URL to access this repo port 8080

There's of course a lot more going on but that's as simple as it gets

Is this setup doable in my own linux box, VM or a cloud instance (Docker Container --> clone, build and deploy from git repo)? What would I need without messing too much with networking and domains etc?

from my research I see the following tools:

1. Kubernetes
2. Dokku : I see it described as "Your own Heroko"

I also keep hearing about CaaS (Containers as a Service)

I understand I would be needing another tool or process to the build (CI/CD) capability, and to triggering builds with git push.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are **off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: question asking : is this possible? how to do it?

Comment: please read where it says : Is this setup doable in my own linux box, VM or a cloud instance (Docker Container --> clone, build and deploy from git repo)? What would I need without messing too much with networking and domains etc?

Comment: If you want to do it on your own box, why not use OpenShift and ``oc cluster up``? This allows you run up an OpenShift instance within yoru existing Docker instance. https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/master/docs/cluster_up_down.md

Comment: looks extremely promising, thanks @GrahamDumpleton